# UIControl not receive touches

Tags: iphone, ios

in my iPhone application I load view from .xib file. In .xib I have such structure: main view with type UIControl, which contains UITable and UIView. The problem is that UIControl not receive touches, and method on event touch down never calls. How can I resolve this issue?

In .h file I have declare method

`- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;`
and in .m I implement this method:

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
{
    [passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [usernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

alse bind backgroundTap event from File's owner with touch dowm event from UIControl of main view

**Update**

Actually the reason is that I click on I always click on UiTable element and so my event not reach. How can I solve this problem, maybe I can send touchdown event from table to UIControl?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
yourControl.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your method control I think it is not touch up inside so make it touch up inside and try.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like your xib root view is a UIControl? IB won't allow that through the UI, did you manually change the class from the initial UIView? Similarly, IB won't allow you to add subviews to a UIControl object. So, without clearly knowing your xib structure, it sounds like you should start with a UIView root and add your UITableView and UIControl objects within the UIView and not the UITableView within the UIControl.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the control that covers all the screen.

Override `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method to redirect touches to your control.